# Может ли сайт отследить Selenium бота?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

В правилах сайта указано, что запрещаются боты. Каким образом сайт может вычислить бота? Сразу можно исключить поведенческий анализ.

Comment: А чем по вашему мелкие конторы отличаются от крупных ? Вопрос только в навыках программиста, который делал их код. Все боты отслеживаются по статистике обращений. ну не может человек выполнять однотипные действия на протяжении многих часов. Плюс к этому конечно куча дополнительных техник, которые например использует сейчас google-капча, которая сама определяет человека по событиям возникающим на странице (таким как движение мыши, боты обычно мышью вообще не двигают)

Comment: Поведенческий анализ можно подделать

Comment: За что минусы? Аналогичный вопрос на соседних форумах имеет положительный показатель up-vote's.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan: Например, за то, что вопрос очевидно направлен на намеренный обход правил сайта (хотя и немного завуалирован). Не всем нравится такое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TL;DR:` может.

Банально свойство `navigator.webdriver` в WebDriver будет возвращать `true`, в то время как в обычном браузере это будет `undefined`.

Сам `WebDriver` может содержать на клиентской стороне массу информации которая присуща только автоматизированным браузерам.

Есть специализированные решения которые умеют определять Selenium ботов и не только, например: https://www.distilnetworks.com, и как они заявляют о своем продукте - никакие искусственные задержки и рандомайзеры поведения не являются препятствием что бы определить бот это или человек.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) можно найти больше примеров как можно определить `Selenium` ли это.

BTW, не забывайте что Selenium проектировался как QA Automation инструмент, но не как Bot-SDK.

Comment: Получается что скрыть бота невозможно?

Comment: @МаксимБатманов, всё зависит от целевого сайта. там может быть как простая проверка на `navigator.webdriver` которую можно легко обойти, так и сложные алгоритмы анализа вашего поведения на сайте + капчи. Чем больше решений для фильтра ботов на сайте - тем дороже он обходится владельцу. К тому же почти на любом сайте боты - это не означает что сразу плохо. Боты есть как полезные так и вредные. Например если вы хотите выполнить действиеХ на сайте по команде через телеграмм - то тут для большинства нету ничего плохого. А если это накрутка в цикле `while(true)` - то такое никто не любит.

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. И не только с помощью navigator.webdriver=true.
Есть и другие незаметные способы. Так что будьте острожны и не воруйте данные у фейсбука. ;)

Comment: Неплохо было бы дополнить ответ, какие именно есть «другие незаметные способы». Спасибо.